# How to resolve error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 55: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pymysql, mysql-connector-python

I am having some kind of encoding error when using SQLAlchemy with mysql+mysqlconnector.
I found a lot of similar questions answered on StackOverflow but none of them seem to work for me. Think I have tried everything. I have tried setting charset=utf8 in the connection string.
I have tried setting the character set using SQL.
`src_conn.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4")`

This is the initial error I got:

```
ExceptionTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "transfer_binlog.py", line 73, in <module>
    events = events.fetchall()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 1216, in fetchall
    e, None, None, self.cursor, self.context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1478, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 1211, in fetchall
    l = self.process_rows(self._fetchall_impl())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py", line 1161, in _fetchall_impl
    return self.cursor.fetchall()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 990, in fetchall
    row, self.description))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/conversion.py", line 407, in row_to_python
    result[i] = self._cache_field_types[field_type](row[i], field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/conversion.py", line 567, in _STRING_to_python
    return value.decode(self.charset)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 55: invalid continuation byte
```

And here is an excerpt of the code:

```
src_connect = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://user:pw@host/core?charset=utf8', isolation_level="READ UNCOMMITTED")
src_conn = src_connect.connect()
events = src_conn.execute("SHOW BINLOG EVENTS")
x = events.fetchall()
```

Is there anything I can have missed or is sqlalchemy or mysql+mysqlconnector driver buggy?
Anya ideas are appreciated

**EDIT**: According to @GordThompsons advice I switched to mysql+pymysql.

There error is now (quite similar):

```
ExceptionTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 581, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1082, in read
    self._read_result_packet(first_packet)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1152, in _read_result_packet
    self._read_rowdata_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1190, in _read_rowdata_packet
    rows.append(self._read_row_from_packet(packet))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1206, in _read_row_from_packet
    data = data.decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 55: invalid continuation byte
```

**EDIT 2**
@GordThompson it sais

```
'collation_connection','utf8mb4_general_ci'
'collation_database','utf8_general_ci'
'collation_server','utf8_general_ci'
```

I also  tried SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'char%'; which give me

```
'character_set_client','utf8mb4'
'character_set_connection','utf8mb4'
'character_set_database','utf8'
'character_set_filesystem','binary'
'character_set_results','utf8mb4'
'character_set_server','latin1'
'character_set_system','utf8'
'character_sets_dir','/rdsdbbin/mysql-5.6.44.R1/share/charsets/'
```

It is strange that character_set_server shows latin1, maybe that is the issue since I guess SHOW BINLOG EVENTS is a server feature.

But then I changed it like this: `SET SESSION character_set_server=utf8;` but the problem remains.
And just to be clear I runned the above statements in MySQLWorkbench and not from python.

Comment: `mysql+mysqlconnector` is not recommended. Try using `mysql+pymysql` instead. ref: [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqlconnector)

Comment: Thank you @GordThompson I have tried this now but the problem is similar, see my edited post.

Comment: 0xE5 is 'å' in the latin1 character set. Is it likely that your query would return string values that contain such a character? (I just tried `SHOW BINLOG EVENTS` on my test MySQL server but it doesn't return anything.)

Comment: @GordThompson yes that is very likely. I use a test string of åäöåäö just to make sure special characters work.

Comment: @GordThompson  Maybe SHOW BINLOG EVENTS really outputs latin1 encoded data I wonder, because I tried to change encoding to latin1 and it does not crash

Comment: What does `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%'` say? Maybe the server or database charset/collation has an effect on the output.

Comment: Can you try executing `SET NAMES 'utf8'` immediately after connecting? It's an old workaround that has been mostly deprecated (and explicitly disallowed with some newer drivers), but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: My current understanding is that it is unsolvable. Now I am trying the command line tool mysqlbinlog instead which gives me the same functionality but with correct results. I am not sure if it is solvable in Python but it felt like I did hit a dead end.